# Firebase rules - Allow read if user's uid equals document's field value userId

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to only allow reads coins's documents if the user's uid matches the userId (encircled in red).

[image]

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if false;
    }
    
    match /coins/{coinId} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null && resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
        allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This rule returns an error in the console when I log into my account. And no data is displayed.
`Uncaught error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Based on everything I've read here it seems like the following code should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using to make update ops? Also how are you fetching coin IDs to update

Comment: That rule looks correct at first glance, so the problem is likely elsewhere. As Dharmaraj asked, can you show the minimal code that we can run against these rules to get the problem? In that code, make sure to show that the rules are met, for example by logging the UID right before trying to access the database.